# Why is this Python/Requests statement not resulting in an error?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

My goal is to use a proxy to scrape certain websites for some data.

My code is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

proxies = {'socks4': 'http://162.144.66.22:16603'}

r = requests.get("http://google.com", proxies=proxies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print(r)
print(soup)
```

The problem is that it appears the proxy may not be being used. As when I change the proxies dictionary to a random number, it still returns status 200 and the html. Any ideas why this is happening? Is it using the proxy or not?

Results:

```
<Response [200]>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"/><meta content="noodp" name="robots"/><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"/><title>Google</title><script nonce="ogEjPeXsr0ScuC6g9Ol/1g==">(function(){window.google={kEI:'N-GTYYidKsXKtQaYh6a4Bg',kEXPI:'0,1302536,56873,6059,206,4804,2316,383,246,5,1354,4012,924,315,1122515,1197760,625,328882,51224,16114,28684,17572,4859,1361,9291,3022,17586,4020,978,13228,3847,4192,6430,1142,20680,919,1832,3249,889,704,1279,2212,530,149,1103,840,1983,214,4100,3514,606,2023,1777,520,14670,3227,2845,7,5599,6755,5096,11625,2771,1926,906,2,941,2614,12710,432,3,346,1244,1,5445,148,11323,991,1661,4,1528,2304,7039,74,1983,2627,2014,11501,3824,1012,2038,2658,7356,31,894,1,10518,2215,1592,713,675,1457,15351,1435,5830,2527,4094,17,3121,6,908,3,3541,1,14261,450,1813,283,912,5992,12346,2332,769,8,1,2987,2,9212,627,4,32,4,4143,1244,4,683,442,342,255,55,4,2811,123,1557,743,2351,3502,1576,3,7826,49,1009,1160,6190,2,508,2380,2719,3708,2,5566,4893,4127,1,8,3022,4696,4568,2577,3132,278,271,1107,5525,85,1,3779,3,1514,2,2920,3147,545,3751,1039,438,5672,516,414,46,3273,1720,2072,701,69,2495,2183,2,1037,44,217,1156,285,1253,41,833,341,2,1096,330,3,2,20,3,2,121,2204,341,225,1161,352,4,99,122,373,201,1007,61,792,239,20,155,4,7,52,31,33,335,111,2,2,1,332,613,95,367,852,731,550,1587,114,449,81,1371,434,103,3390,28,142,263,147,60,4,49,584,18,1258,401,282,127,192,209,328,4,52,29,5,507,245,532,2,684,1234,780,404,2,98,369,7,2,2,2,3,3,1,7,3,1,2,3,2,2,8,7,187,852,117,283,12,635,183,74,131,732,6,2,708,54,853,2,252,1170,499,5532101,100,346,313,16,1802560,4193980,2800696,882,444,1,2,80,1,1796,1,9,2553,1,748,141,795,563,1,4265,1,1,2,1331,4142,2609,155,17,13,72,139,4,2,20,2,169,13,19,46,5,39,96,548,29,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,7,4,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,353,513,186,1,1,158,3,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,3,3,269,551,782,49,8,16,4,9,5,20,45,1,30,4,2,16,2,17,20733141,3220020,4041352,338,3,2414,1491,9,1435,157,1360,291,115,3900,2886,501,655,810367',kBL:'4bzV'};google.sn='webhp';google.kHL='en';})();(function(){
var f=this||self;var h,k=[];function l(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||h}function m(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b}
function n(a,b,c,d,g){var e="";c||-1!==b.search("&ei=")||(e="&ei="+l(d),-1===b.search("&lei=")&&(d=m(d))&&(e+="&lei="+d));d="";!c&&f._cshid&&-1===b.search("&cshid=")&&"slh"!==a&&(d="&cshid="+f._cshid);c=c||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+e+"&zx="+Date.now()+d;/^http:/i.test(c)&&"https:"===window.location.protocol&&(google.ml&&google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:c,glmm:1}),c="");return c};h=google.kEI;google.getEI=l;google.getLEI=m;google.ml=function(){return null};google.log=function(a,b,c,d,g){if(c=n(a,b,c,d,g)){a=new Image;var e=k.length;k[e]=a;a.onerror=a.onload=a.onabort=function(){delete k[e]};a.src=c}};google.logUrl=n;}).call(this);(function(){
google.y={};google.sy=[];google.x=function(a,b){if(a)var c=a.id;else{do c=Math.random();while(google.y[c])}google.y[c]=[a,b];return!1};google.sx=function(a){google.sy.push(a)};google.lm=[];google.plm=function(a){google.lm.push.apply(google.lm,a)};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};google.bx=!1;google.lx=function(){};}).call(this);google.f={};(function(){
document.documentElement.addEventListener("submit",function(b){var a;if(a=b.target){var c=a.getAttribute("data-submitfalse");a="1"===c||"q"===c&&!a.elements.q.value?!0:!1}else a=!1;a&&(b.preventDefault(),b.stopPropagation())},!0);document.documentElement.addEventListener("click",function(b){var a;a:{for(a=b.target;a&&a!==document.documentElement;a=a.parentElement)if("A"===a.tagName){a="1"===a.getAttribute("data-nohref");break a}a=!1}a&&b.preventDefault()},!0);}).call(this);</script><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}
</style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#1558d6}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}body{background:#fff;color:#000}a{color:#4b11a8;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#1558d6}a:visited{color:#4b11a8}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#f8f9fa;border:solid 1px;border-color:#dadce0 #70757a #70757a #dadce0;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}#WqQANb a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#dadce0}.lst:focus{outline:none}</style><script nonce="ogEjPeXsr0ScuC6g9Ol/1g==">(function(){window.google.erd={sp:'hp',jsr:0,bv:1476,de:true};
var f=this||self;var g,h,k=null!==(g=f.mei)&&void 0!==g?g:1,l=null!==(h=f.sdo)&&void 0!==h?h:!0,n=0,p,q=google.erd,t=q.jsr;google.ml=function(a,b,e,m,d){d=void 0===d?2:d;b&&(p=a&&a.message);if(google.dl)return google.dl(a,d,e),null;if(0>t){window.console&&console.error(a,e);if(-2===t)throw a;b=!1}else b=!a||!a.message||"Error loading script"===a.message||n>=k&&!m?!1:!0;if(!b)return null;n++;e=e||{};b=encodeURIComponent;var c="/gen_204?atyp=i&ei="+b(google.kEI);google.kEXPI&&(c+="&jexpid="+b(google.kEXPI));c+="&srcpg="+b(google.sn)+"&jsr="+b(q.jsr)+"&bver="+b(q.bv)+("&jsel="+d);for(var r in e)c+="&",c+=b(r),c+="=",c+=
b(e[r]);c=c+"&emsg="+b(a.name+": "+a.message);c=c+"&jsst="+b(a.stack||"N/A");12288<=c.length&&(c=c.substr(0,12288));a=c;m||google.log(0,"",a);return a};window.onerror=function(a,b,e,m,d){p!==a&&(a=d instanceof Error?d:Error(a),google.ml(a,!1,void 0,!1,"SyntaxError"===a.name||"SyntaxError"===a.message.substring(0,11)?2:0));p=null;l&&n>=k&&(window.onerror=null)};})();</script></head><body bgcolor="#fff"><script nonce="ogEjPeXsr0ScuC6g9Ol/1g==">(function(){var src='/images/nav_logo229.png';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}
if (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}
}
})();</script><div id="mngb"><div id="gbar"><nobr><b class="gb1">Search</b> <a class="gb1" href="http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&amp;tab=wi">Images</a> <a class="gb1" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;tab=wl">Maps</a> <a class="gb1" href="https://play.google.com/?hl=en&amp;tab=w8">Play</a> <a class="gb1" href="http://www.youtube.com/?gl=US&amp;tab=w1">YouTube</a> <a class="gb1" href="https://news.google.com/?tab=wn">News</a> <a class="gb1" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a> <a class="gb1" href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">Drive</a> <a class="gb1" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh" style="text-decoration:none"><u>More</u> »</a></nobr></div><div id="guser" width="100%"><nobr><span class="gbi" id="gbn"></span><span class="gbf" id="gbf"></span><span id="gbe"></span><a class="gb4" href="http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en">Web History</a> | <a class="gb4" href="/preferences?hl=en">Settings</a> | <a class="gb4" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&amp;passive=true&amp;continue=http://www.google.com/&amp;ec=GAZAAQ" id="gb_70" target="_top">Sign in</a></nobr></div><div class="gbh" style="left:0"></div><div class="gbh" style="right:0"></div></div><center><br clear="all" id="lgpd"/><div id="lga"><img alt="Google" height="92" id="hplogo" src="/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png" style="padding:28px 0 14px" width="272"/><br/><br/></div><form action="/search" name="f"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr valign="top"><td width="25%"> </td><td align="center" nowrap=""><input name="ie" type="hidden" value="ISO-8859-1"/><input name="hl" type="hidden" value="en"/><input name="source" type="hidden" value="hp"/><input name="biw" type="hidden"/><input name="bih" type="hidden"/><div class="ds" style="height:32px;margin:4px 0"><input autocomplete="off" class="lst" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57" style="margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top;color:#000" title="Google Search" value=""/></div><br style="line-height:0"/><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" name="btnG" type="submit" value="Google Search"/></span></span><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" id="tsuid1" name="btnI" type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky"/><script nonce="ogEjPeXsr0ScuC6g9Ol/1g==">(function(){var id='tsuid1';document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){if (this.form.q.value){this.checked = 1;if (this.form.iflsig)this.form.iflsig.disabled = false;}
else top.location='/doodles/';};})();</script><input name="iflsig" type="hidden" value="ALs-wAMAAAAAYZPvR3XeA_2hvvUXKtup1vz1LZFktom0"/></span></span></td><td align="left" class="fl sblc" nowrap="" width="25%"><a href="/advanced_search?hl=en&amp;authuser=0">Advanced search</a></td></tr></table><input id="gbv" name="gbv" type="hidden" value="1"/><script nonce="ogEjPeXsr0ScuC6g9Ol/1g==">(function(){
var a,b="1";if(document&&document.getElementById)if("undefined"!=typeof XMLHttpRequest)b="2";else if("undefined"!=typeof ActiveXObject){var c,d,e=["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];for(c=0;d=e[c++];)try{new ActiveXObject(d),b="2"}catch(h){}}a=b;if("2"==a&&-1==location.search.indexOf("&gbv=2")){var f=google.gbvu,g=document.getElementById("gbv");g&&(g.value=a);f&&window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=f},0)};}).call(this);</script></form><div id="gac_scont"></div><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em"><br/></div><span id="footer"><div style="font-size:10pt"><div id="WqQANb" style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center"><a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising Programs</a><a href="/services/">Business Solutions</a><a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a></div></div><p style="font-size:8pt;color:#70757a">© 2021 - <a href="/intl/en/policies/privacy/">Privacy</a> - <a href="/intl/en/policies/terms/">Terms</a></p></span></center><script nonce="ogEjPeXsr0ScuC6g9Ol/1g==">(function(){window.google.cdo={height:757,width:1440};(function(){
var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b){var c=window.document,d="CSS1Compat"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body;a=d.clientWidth;b=d.clientHeight}a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)&&google.log("","","/client_204?&atyp=i&biw="+a+"&bih="+b+"&ei="+google.kEI);}).call(this);})();</script> <script nonce="ogEjPeXsr0ScuC6g9Ol/1g==">(function(){google.xjs={ck:'',cs:'',excm:[]};})();</script> <script nonce="ogEjPeXsr0ScuC6g9Ol/1g==">(function(){var u='/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.0nQ8X6LkAxI.O/am\x3dACcAVg/d\x3d1/ed\x3d1/esmo\x3d1/rs\x3dACT90oFK4c5-TQYA7GFcdnA53Ix1Arix4g/m\x3dsb_he,d';
var e=this||self,f=function(a){return a};var g;var l=function(a,b){this.g=b===h?a:""};l.prototype.toString=function(){return this.g+""};var h={};
function m(){var a=u;google.lx=function(){n(a);google.lx=function(){}};google.bx||google.lx()}
function n(a){google.timers&&google.timers.load&&google.tick&&google.tick("load","xjsls");var b=document;var c="SCRIPT";"application/xhtml+xml"===b.contentType&&(c=c.toLowerCase());c=b.createElement(c);if(void 0===g){b=null;var k=e.trustedTypes;if(k&&k.createPolicy){try{b=k.createPolicy("goog#html",{createHTML:f,createScript:f,createScriptURL:f})}catch(p){e.console&&e.console.error(p.message)}g=b}else g=b}a=(b=g)?b.createScriptURL(a):a;a=new l(a,h);c.src=a instanceof l&&a.constructor===l?a.g:"type_error:TrustedResourceUrl";var d;a=(c.ownerDocument&&c.ownerDocument.defaultView||window).document;(d=(b=null===(d=a.querySelector)||void 0===d?void 0:d.call(a,"script[nonce]"))?b.nonce||b.getAttribute("nonce")||"":"")&&c.setAttribute("nonce",d);document.body.appendChild(c);google.psa=!0};setTimeout(function(){m()},0);})();(function(){window.google.xjsu='/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.0nQ8X6LkAxI.O/am\x3dACcAVg/d\x3d1/ed\x3d1/esmo\x3d1/rs\x3dACT90oFK4c5-TQYA7GFcdnA53Ix1Arix4g/m\x3dsb_he,d';})();function _DumpException(e){throw e;}
function _F_installCss(c){}
(function(){google.jl={attn:false,blt:'none',chnk:0,dw:false,dwu:true,emtn:0,end:0,ine:false,lls:'default',pdt:0,rep:0,snet:true,strt:0,ubm:false,uwp:true};})();(function(){var pmc='{\x22d\x22:{},\x22sb_he\x22:{\x22agen\x22:true,\x22cgen\x22:true,\x22client\x22:\x22heirloom-hp\x22,\x22dh\x22:true,\x22dhqt\x22:true,\x22ds\x22:\x22\x22,\x22ffql\x22:\x22en\x22,\x22fl\x22:true,\x22host\x22:\x22google.com\x22,\x22isbh\x22:28,\x22jsonp\x22:true,\x22msgs\x22:{\x22cibl\x22:\x22Clear Search\x22,\x22dym\x22:\x22Did you mean:\x22,\x22lcky\x22:\x22I\\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky\x22,\x22lml\x22:\x22Learn more\x22,\x22oskt\x22:\x22Input tools\x22,\x22psrc\x22:\x22This search was removed from your \\u003Ca href\x3d\\\x22/history\\\x22\\u003EWeb History\\u003C/a\\u003E\x22,\x22psrl\x22:\x22Remove\x22,\x22sbit\x22:\x22Search by image\x22,\x22srch\x22:\x22Google Search\x22},\x22ovr\x22:{},\x22pq\x22:\x22\x22,\x22refpd\x22:true,\x22rfs\x22:[],\x22sbas\x22:\x220 3px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)\x22,\x22sbpl\x22:16,\x22sbpr\x22:16,\x22scd\x22:10,\x22stok\x22:\x229dnURCIg88JrBfNLoHlile_Fe8M\x22,\x22uhde\x22:false}}';google.pmc=JSON.parse(pmc);})();</script> </body></html>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Beautiful Soup seems to be irrelevant, the question is about `requests.get()` and proxies.

Comment: You're right I would say. I just included it for context.

Comment: Your `proxies` dictionary is not correct. See the example [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#socks)

Comment: Your request isn't going through the proxy, since there's no `http` key in the `proxies` dictionary.